Using PostGIS to find the Intersection of Linear Features on only the Buffer of Polygon Features
I am using PostGIS and I need to find where linear features (mylines) intersect only the buffer of polygon features (mypoly). I used the following code, which works, but it is taking 13.369 seconds to complete the query. This does not sound like much, but I am using a relatively small dataset and the time will increase dramatically as the dataset gets larger. Is there a way to improve the performance of this query. I have spent a week on this and I just cannot improve the performance. Appreciate any and all help!
SELECT id, i.clipped_geom
FROM mylines AS a
Cross JOIN Lateral (SELECT (ST_Intersection(ST_UnaryUnion((ST_Multi(ST_Difference((ST_Buffer(ST_Transform((ST_MakeValid(b.geom)),26913),50)),ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b.geom),26913))))),ST_Transform(a.geom,26913))) AS clipped_geom
FROM mypoly b
WHERE st_intersects(ST_Transform(a.geom,26913),ST_Transform(b.geom,26913))) AS i

Please note I altered the query just a bit, with the same performance results. The following image shows the Analysis and Spatial Indexes. Please bare with me as I am relatively new to PostGIS - let me know if I need to provide more information:


you are always applying  ST_Transform, but do you have any spatial index on those transformed geometries? Clearly, showing the schema of the table as well as the analyzed query plan would be helpful and give more insights.

Hi UninformedUser, I appreciate your quick response. I included screenshots of the Analysis and Spatial Indexes on the two layers. I also altered the query a bit. Please bare with me as I am relatively new to PostGIS.
